# how to avoid duplicate class in c++ without namespace

Tags: c++, duplicates

just guess a situation that main.cpp should include both 'a.h' and 'b.h', and class 'C' is defined in both a.h and b.h but its member functions's names are same but differnt, that is version of class 'c' is different. but, main.cpp require both version of class 'C'.

Then how to avoid errors from the issue??

Comment: You do realize that the problem you want to solve is reason namespace(s) were introduced into C++?

Comment: Answer is: yes. Or 42, can't be sure!

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to define two different classes with the same (fully qualified) name; that's not allowed. Rename one of them, or put it in a different namespace.

Answer (score 1):

> Then how to avoid errors from the issue??

With namespaces, as you say. If you do not like namespaces, change your opinion.

It is illegal to have two symbols with the same name but different meaning.

And that's that.